# NullPointerException in twitter4j TwitterFactory.getInstance()

Tags: nullpointerexception, twitter4j

I'm trying to get a twitter object for OAuth but it returns the following exception.

The update code is as follows.

```
  ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    Log.i(TAG, "configuration buildr initiated");
    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey(consumerKey)
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret(consumerSecretKey);
    Log.i(TAG, "consumer keys set");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());
    Log.i(TAG,"Twitter factory initiated");
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();
    Log.i(TAG,"twiiter instance obtaines");
    try {
        RequestToken requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken();
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

There is a NullPointerException thrown here and I cant figure out why. What is the problem with the code?

The stack trace is as follows:

```
03-08 14:53:12.510: W/dalvikvm(21320): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4182dda0)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320): Process: org.ambientdynamix.core, PID: 21320
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.doImplicitBootDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1721)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.searchDynamicImports(BundleWiringImpl.java:1698)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.findClassOrResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1534)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl.getResourceByDelegation(BundleWiringImpl.java:1440)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleWiringImpl$BundleClassLoader.getResource(BundleWiringImpl.java:2458)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(ClassLoader.java:430)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream(Class.java:1037)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfiguration.<init>(PropertyConfiguration.java:129)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfiguration.<init>(PropertyConfiguration.java:146)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder.<init>(ConfigurationBuilder.java:31)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.ambientdynamix.contextplugins.ambientTwitter.ambientTwitterRuntime.getDefaultConfigurationView(ambientTwitterRuntime.java:80)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.ambientdynamix.core.DynamixService.doContextPluginConfigurationView(DynamixService.java:2382)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.ambientdynamix.core.DynamixService.openContextPluginConfigurationForFramework(DynamixService.java:2356)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at org.ambientdynamix.ui.adapters.InstalledPluginsListAdapter$4.onClick(InstalledPluginsListAdapter.java:212)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4633)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19330)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
03-08 14:53:12.520: E/AndroidRuntime(21320):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 14:53:12.530: W/ActivityManager(815):   Force finishing activity org.ambientdynamix.core/org.ambientdynamix.ui.activities.HomeActivity
03-08 14:53:12.590: V/Permission(21320): createPermission for permissionString: Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE
```

Is it something to do with what is discussed in this link?
[ClassNotFoundException: twitter4j.conf.PropertyConfigurationFactory : Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15879259/classnotfoundexception-twitter4j-conf-propertyconfigurationfactory-android)

Does the twitter4j.properties file need to be there for ConfigurationBuilder to work? In the android application where should I put this?

Answer (score 1):

In the first call, you have to pass the `Configuration`, in next subsequent calls you can avoid the `Configuration`.

So, use `twitter= new TwitterFactory(configuration).getInstance();`

Comment: Nope adding the ConfigurationBuilder did not help. Check the update code above and the stacktrace.

Comment: At which line NullPointerException was thrown?

Comment: When creating the configuration builder. ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

Comment: tryr `class.forName("twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder");` before that line

Comment: @thigale how can that help me?

Comment: It tells you whether class can be loaded

Comment: Does the twitter4j.properties file need to be there for ConfigurationBuilder to work? In the android application where should I put this?

Comment: No. Its not required if you are using `ConfigurationBuilder`